# frequency table with dplyr in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this:

```
set.seed(123)
class = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
have <- data.frame(ID = c(1:12), CLUSTER = rep(1:4, 3), VAL = sample(class, 12, replace = TRUE))
```

I want this:

```
want <- data.frame(CLUSTER = c(1,2,3,4), D = c(2, 2, 0, 2), C = c(0, 1, 0, 0), A = c(1, 0, 2, 0), B = c(0, 0, 1, 1))
```

I want to do this with `dplyr` as there are other columns in my original data which I want to summarize.

I was looking for something like :

```
have %>% group_by(CLUSTER) %>% table(VAL) %>% summarize(sum(OTHER_VARS)) %>% mutate(OTHER_VARS)
```

I know I can use `table` or `xtabs` or `count` in `dplyr` but it either loses the data frame class or converts data to long instead of wide.

thanks.

Comment: Please use `set.seed(x)` first when using `sample` - otherwise your `have` and `want` are not reproducible. Can you edit please? (And no, i'm not the downvoter)

Comment: Check your output. It doesn't match the input

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a way to handle this with `dplyr`, but here is a solution using `reshape2`.

```r
library(reshape2)
set.seed(123)

class <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
have <- data.frame(ID = c(1:12), 
                   CLUSTER = rep(1:4, 3), 
                   VAL = sample(class, 12, replace = TRUE))

dcast(have, CLUSTER ~ VAL)
```

I believe this does what you have in mind; `dcast()` returns a `data.frame` object. But once again, `dplyr` can probably handle this easily, too.

Answer (score 0):

Not that there's anything wrong with `dplyr`, but I think you *could* use `table` to get a `data.frame` solution:

```
> t1 <- table(have$CLUSTER, have$VAL) #create using table()

    A B C D
  1 0 1 1 1
  2 1 1 0 1
  3 0 1 1 1
  4 0 1 0 2

> t1 <- data.frame(t1) #convert to data.frame

   Var1 Var2 Freq
1     1    A    0
2     2    A    1
         .....
15    3    D    1
16    4    D    2

> t1 <- reshape(t1, idvar = 'Var1', timevar = 'Var2', direction = 'wide') #convert to wide

      Var1 Freq.A Freq.B Freq.C Freq.D
1    1      0      1      1      1
2    2      1      1      0      1
3    3      0      1      1      1
4    4      0      1      0      2

> names(t1) <- c('CLUSTER', levels(have$VAL)) #rename columns

  CLUSTER A B C D
1       1 0 1 1 1
2       2 1 1 0 1
3       3 0 1 1 1
4       4 0 1 0 2
```

**Edit: A more concise solution without `dplyr` (thanks to @thelatemail):**

```
t1 <- table(have$CLUSTER, have$VAL)
cbind(CLUSTER = rownames(t1), as.data.frame.matrix(t1))
```

Comment: `as.data.frame.matrix(t1)` might be of interest to you.

Comment: Wouldn't that "get rid" of the CLUSTER column, though?

Comment: You could get them back pretty quick - `t1 <- table(have$CLUSTER, have$VAL); cbind(CLUSTER=rownames(t1), as.data.frame.matrix(t1) )`